# zmq.error.ZMQError: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: amazon-ec2, zeromq, pyzmq

I have the following pull - publisher ZMQ schema on an Amazon EC2 machine:

I am working with the Public IP address of my EC2 Amazon machine.

I am trying send data via ZMQ **`PUSH`** socket from the client side to ZMQ **`PULL`** socket server side, which is this:

```
import zmq
from zmq.log.handlers import PUBHandler
import logging
# from zmq.asyncio import Context

def main():
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    publisher = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    # publisher.bind("tcp://*:5557")
    publisher.bind("tcp://54.89.25.43:5557")

    handler = PUBHandler(publisher)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    print("Network Manager CNVSS Broker listening")

    collector = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
    # collector.bind("tcp://*:5558")
    collector.bind("tcp://54.89.25.43:5558")

    while True:
        message = collector.recv()
        print("Publishing update %s" % message)
        publisher.send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I excute this script, I get this error:

```
(cnvss_nm) ubuntu@ip-172-31-55-72:~/cnvss_nm$ python pull_pub-nm.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pull_pub-nm.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "pull_pub-nm.py", line 10, in main
    publisher.bind("tcp://54.89.25.43:5557")
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 547, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Cannot assign requested address
(cnvss_nm) ubuntu@ip-172-31-55-72:~/cnvss_nm$
```

I've changed my IP-address to `publisher.bind("tcp://*:5557")` and `collector.bind("tcp://*:5558")` in the server side, and my script is running:

```
(cnvss_nm) ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~/cnvss_nm$ python pull_pub-nm.py 
Network Manager CNVSS Broker listening
```

But from my [**client**-side code](https://pastebin.com/LAcqfbCZ) ( [added recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422619/zmq-error-zmqerror-cannot-assign-requested-address/50426297?noredirect=1#comment87893867_50426297) ), any data is sent.

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zmq.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "zhelpers.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    /*
    std::cout << "Sending message to NM Server…\n" << std::endl; */

    zmq::socket_t subscriber(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5557");
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);

    zmq::socket_t sender(context, ZMQ_PUSH);
    sender.connect("tcp://localhost:5558");

    string firstMessage = "Hola, soy el cliente 1";

    while (1)
    {
        //  Wait for next request from client
        std::string string = s_recv(subscriber);

        std::cout << "Received request: " << string << std::endl;

        // Do some 'work'
        // sleep(1);

        //  Send reply back to client
        // zmq::message_t message(firstMessage.size() + 1);

        // Cualquiera de los dos se puede
        // memcpy(message.data(), firstMessage.c_str(), firstMessage.size() + 1);
        // s_send(sender, "Hola soy un responder 1");

        // sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

I think that my inconvenient is on my EC2 machine network configuration or on the way of setup the IP address of the server.

When I test the clients and server locally, all it works perfectly.

Is there any possibility of performing some forwarding or NAT operation on my EC2 machine?

My clients do not reach the server.

I have the security groups rule the above mentioned ports 5557 and 5558.

How to solve this inconvenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How to **solve** this inconvenience?*

**1 )**
If in doubts about the EC2 addresses, first try to test the reversed **`.bind() / .connect()`**, so that the EC2-side localhost address assignments are out f the game, and your connectivity proof towards a known IP-address will not depend on the EC2-side settings.

**2 )**
Next, given there are no details about the client-side part of the MCVE, I may have got the scenario idea incorectly, so bear with me - there are only these compatible ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Archetype *sockets'* matches available ever since, up to API v4.2.x in 2018/Q2:

```
{ PUB:  [  SUB,
          XSUB,
          None
          ],
  PULL: [ PUSH,
          None
          ],
  ...
  }
```

**3 )**
There is a good engineering practice not to let unhandled exceptions happen, the more, if `Context()`-instance may still bear the possession of IP:PORT# (b)locked resource ( sometimes even beyond the python process termination ( many incidents with my own naive and this way deadlocked experiments in my past dark history :o) )

Each step in the infrastructure setup ought be wrapped into error-handling syntax-clause, best including a `finally:` section, where so far created resources will occasionally get dismantled in a graceful manner in cases, when exception(s) spring out. This way your code will prevent a forever hanging orphan(s), that have just an option to reboot the platform so as to get rid of these, otherwise impossible to salvage, hostages.

---

### Problem solved,
a final summary :

The initially indicated problem ( diagnosed at `.bind() / .connect()` phase ) was, as depicted earlier, related to Amazon EC2 instance IP-address mapping, as the term, needed for any transport-class Endpoint setup, **`localhost:port#`**

> [*camdebu on Nov 1, **2012** 5:07 PM*](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=396747#396747) explained all the steps needed:
> <sub>Setup an Elastic IP to your EC2 isntance. You will then have a static IP address. There's no cost for the Elastic IP as long as you have it pointed to an EC2 instance.</sub>
>
> <sub>You should then have no problem connecting to your new IP Address and port as long as your security group is setup correctly.
>   -Cam-</sub>
>
> - <sub>Check your Security Group Rule. Make sure you allow the port to communicate from outside the instance. (Enable All TCP and Check). *[ added Yesu Jeya Bensh.P ]*</sub>

The recently posted client-code but shows another issue, a **mutual block**, generated by a **non-cooperating** `zmq::socket_t` **`sender( context, ZMQ_PUSH )`**, which actually never sends a single message.

Given the client goes into `while(1)`-loop as posted above, the associated peer will inadvertently get into an unsalvageable blocked state inside the python-made `main()`, since :

```
def main():
    ...
    collector = ctx.socket( zmq.PULL )
    #ollector.bind( "tcp://*:5558"           )
    collector.bind( "tcp://54.89.25.43:5558" )

    while True:
        message = collector.recv()           # THIS SLOC WILL BLOCK FOREVER HERE,
        ...                                  #      GIVEN <sender> NEVER SENDS...
```

so more care is to be taken, so as to make the flow of events robust enough, not to ever fall into this or similar unsalvageable mutual block.

Comment: Hi friend Thanks for their recommendations. With respect them: **1.**  What does it mean  the **reversed** `.bind() / .connect()`. I  try my code in a local network environment (two machines connected  in the same switch) with EC2 out of the game and the process messaging it's works.     **2** From the client side, I have two sockets: a `ZMQ_PUSH` socket which connect with the `ZMQ_PULL` socket on the server. And a `ZMQ_SUB` socket which connect with the `ZMQ_PUB` socket on the server. Of this way my sockets definition according to my architecture or ZMQ pattern, those are compatibles.

Comment: With respect to **third option - 3**,  I think that is a good alternative manage some exceptions in relation to connectivity or connections in my ZMQ workflow ... But, why is the reason to my architecture works inside a local network environment and not on Server located on amazon EC2? Just in case ... If you need know about of the client code section, I will put here ...

Comment: The **reversed** means, that a side, which originally used to `.bind()` will now try to `.connect()` instead and vice versa, which has zero net effect on ZeroMQ infrastructure setup, yet may solve your platform IP-addressing uncertainties. Next, if properly error-handled, the code will advise you about the reason, where and why it fails at proceeding in the desired direction. **Yes**, posting a complete MCVE, including all parts and data to reproduce a problem, is a known StackOverflow **standard of quality**.

Comment: Hi friend.  [One answer in this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84401) give me the elements to solve the inconvenient. In amazon ec2 is  necessary setup an Elastic IP  address and associate it to my ec2 instance. With this, I solve my problem. [My code client side is here](https://pastebin.com/LAcqfbCZ). With respect to handle errors. Can I think in work with `try` - `exception` - `finally` ... [like this?](https://blog.apcelent.com/how-to-setup-microservices-python-zeromq-docker-example.html)
Any recommendations?

Comment: Hi again. You're right, and I've sent the client code wrong, my apologies. It happens that I have the following scheme:   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDyPW.png "PUB/SUB+PUSH/PULL Messaging Broker") [My real client code sender is this](https://pastebin.com/KE07ehdF). Is similar to previous, but this client really sends the message.

Comment: I am currently implementing your  best practice recommendations to apply the `ZMQ_LINGER`,  `ZMQ_INVERT_MATCHING`,  `ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TTL`, `ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_IVL` directives [with the order to avoid that sender client receive you own data back or that the server sending data back ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289072/zmq-dealer-router-communication). In addition, your tips in this question **helped me to found the solution with my Amazon EC2 instance**. Thanks a lot for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I was using ZMQ on EC2 and getting "Cannot assign requested address."  I was also using Elastic IP as suggested in the answer, but it did not work for me. It turned out that on EC2, the sending side (ZMQ.PUSH) needs to bind to the private IP rather than to the public, while the receiving side needs to bind to the public IP, so trying to bind the server to Elastic IP caused the error. After I changed it to bind the server ZMQ.PUSH side to Private IP and the client ZMQ.PULL to Elastic IP (on the same port), it worked.